# Bundle for iOS simulator 8.1 doesn't appear

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

I have an app and I want to check the content of the main bundle of the application. Basically I go to the following filepath: **User/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator** and there are many folders inside it: 6.0, 6.1, 7.0, 7.0-64, 7.1-64 etc. containing bundles for corresponding applications. But there's no any folder with name 8.x and nothing happens if I launch the app for the simulator with this iOS version.

So what's the reason of the problem? Where can I find what I want? 
I use XCode 6.1, iPhone Simulator 4s, iOS SDK 8.1.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In Xcode 6 and above not creating the above path once print the directory path . Then you know where the bundle file For EX : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/%@",NSHomeDirectory(),kDatabaseName] error:nil];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are now in...

Users/**YOU**/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices

In that folder are a list of what appear to be GUIDS, in each of those folders is a device.plist, for example...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>UDID</key>
    <string>2E7D8A02-1224-488B-B596-C1F7CA31F3C0</string>
    <key>deviceType</key>
    <string>com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6-Plus</string>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>iPhone 6 Plus</string>
    <key>runtime</key>
    <string>com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-8-0</string>
    <key>state</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

One of the elements is called `name` and you can see in this example `iPhone 6 Plus`, this will help you identify the right folder for the right device

Comment: Yes, that's exaclty what I wanted. Thank you a lot! Any guesses why was this path changed?

Comment: No idea, sorry. Assume they've just changed the way the simulator works

Comment: Thise are not GUIDs.  They are UDIDs.  You can run 'xcrun simctl list' to list all your sim devices and their UDIDs.  It you intend to not run Xcode 5 in the future, you can delete the old paths.

Comment: In **Users/YOU/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices** folder there is a hidden file `.default_created.plist` there you can find folder names of certain simulator.